# I want to keep my UITabBar from every UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2, uistoryboardsegue

[image]

Hello everyone.

Let me explain my problem specifically. In the picture my storyboard can be seen.

- I have got a Tab Bar Navigation Controller
- 1 & 3 are Navigation Controllers which represent 2 tabs of my tab bar navigation controller (there are 5 tabs, my problem is with just one of them)
- UIViewController #2 (notification controller) & #4 (profile settings controller) are my view controllers inside the navigation controllers (#1 & #3)
- I have got a segue from UIViewController #2 to UIViewController #6, which works perfectly and keeps my tabbar visible, as intended.
- UIViewController #5 is inside a scrollview in UIViewController #4 (I have 3 UIViewControllers in this scrollview)
- I have got a segue from UIViewController #5 to UIViewController #6, which works but my **TabBar disappears!**. I want my TabBar to stay visible just like #2 to #6 which I wrote previously.

I understand that the problem is that #5 is not directly connected to a navigation controller. But I need to show #5 in #4 along with other UIViewControllers which can be scrolled.

I tried embedding #5 in a navigation controller as well but it is not working.

I've been trying and searching but couldn't find anything about this situation so I am seeking a way out of this problem. Any help is most appreciated.

Problem is not about segue but if you want to check how I use the segue, both segues are called the same way, but of course with different identifiers:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("openSupport", sender: nil)
```

Using Xcode 7.1, Swift 2, iOS 8+

Comment: how can you have a view controller in a scrollview ?

Comment: can u explain this 'UIViewController #5 is inside a scrollview in UIViewController #4 (I have 3 UIViewControllers in this scrollview)' ?

Comment: instead of doing segueiwhtidentifier, why dont you presnt the view controller 6 with the tabBArController ?

Comment: If you are going to have child view controller's, you should use an embed segue (i.e. embed segue to UIViewController 5 from the scrollview in UIViewController #4)

Comment: @Mr.T I add viedwcontrollers to scrollview like this: scrollView.addSubview(firstTableViewController.view)
            scrollView.addSubview(secondTableViewController.view)